# Android Java Build errors

Tags: java, android, debugging, error-handling, build

I tried to build my project today, because everything worked fine in Android Studio Intellij on my phone. But now there are two things. the first thing is that the build say:

```
Could not open init remapped class cache for 9bbaqp2sgtpoz1dwcumqbqtxg (C:\Users\Max\.gradle\caches\5.4.1\scripts-remapped\ijresolvers_3l0ejc2wfly7v3w1ngwtcqg40\9bbaqp2sgtpoz1dwcumqbqtxg\initdcd040730888da95d185715568c9cc57).
> Could not open init generic class cache for initialization script 'C:\Users\Max\AppData\Local\Temp\ijresolvers.gradle' (C:\Users\Max\.gradle\caches\5.4.1\scripts\9bbaqp2sgtpoz1dwcumqbqtxg\init\initdcd040730888da95d185715568c9cc57).
   > BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '_BuildScript_' Unsupported class file major version 57
```

And the other thing is that in the src/androidTest/java/application/ExampleInstumentedTest is an error with the import:

```
import androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4;
```

After I searched a while I still have no clue what to do please help!

Comment: Clean - rebuild or File - Restart nd Invalidate caches

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to clear Android Studio's cache and bring it out of its state of confusion? If not, select 'File > Invalidate Caches / Restart' and then click the 'Invalidate and Restart' button. Clean and rebuild your project.

Comment: so the error in the exampleInstrumentedTest is gone... thx but the Bug in the build is still there. and it says it is something in my scripts and when I open the library settings there are so many red things...

Comment: @Mindmax Maybe you could try cleaning the gradle cache and the project gradle directory:

`rm -rf $HOME/.gradle/caches/` 

and

`rm -rf $PROJECT/.gradle/caches/ && rm -rf $PROJECT/build/`

Comment: delete everything in it? there is an folder 5.4.1, jars-3, journal-1,moduels-2, transfroms-2

Comment: I would start by deleting the cache mentioned in the error message (\Users\Max\.gradle\caches\5.4.1\scripts). If that doesn't work you could try the above.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the error stack trace you posted appears `Unsupported class file major version 57`, which suggests you should try an earlier version of JDK. If I am not wrong, you have JDK 13. Try version 11 or even version 8.